# Iterating through a VisualForce page to manipulate CSS using document.getElementByClassName("foo")

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css

I am adding CSS classes to numerous `<apex:inputFields>`, that i am passing to the HTML `<input>` element using `html-class="foo"`. Then i am iterating through them like this to change other properties using `Eventhandlers` (not displayed here)
This is my code:

```js
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");
console.log(inputs); // returns HTMLCollection [] of Tags with class *foo*
console.log(inputs[0]); // returns undefined
  for (input of inputs) {
      console.log(input);
      let label = input.parentElement
                       .parentElement
                       .parentElement
                       .getElementsByTagName("label")[0];

      if (input.placeholder || input.value) {
          label.classList.add("is-floating");
      }
  }
```

This is where it gets interesting. I have tested this behavior using standard .html files and it works. However the `input` variable declared in the for/of loop does not return a value when run on a preview VisualForce page. In fact it does not display any result what so ever. While the `inputs` variable returns a HTMLCollection aka an array. I am beyond confused. Did i miss something? This code would work in vanilla JS run in chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out. I had multiple problems here. The main one being that the DOM wasnt yet fully loaded when the function called. Which still kind of confuses me because `window.onload` should trigger when the document is ready, no? Cheers